# rdf for public procurement

Tags: rdf, rdfs, opendata

I've been coming to stackoverflow for years now but never actually signed up...

I have a predicament right now that can't solve.

Doing a linked open data project on public procurement for Portugal

Having said that, I was using both euvoc for public procurement and pproc vocabulary but there is something I cannot use because it does not apply directly to portuguese law: procurement procedure type

Trying to write my first controlled vocab in rdf, and trying my best to reuse other vocabs as much as possible. Since Procurement procedure type is a property of the contract, can i use rdf:subpropertyof? Thing is... these subproperties are not part of the old rdf:scheme...

Kind of lost here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure what you're asking - would be easier to understand if you'd show your current data. "can I use `rdf:subPropertyOf`" for what? You can use it to relate two proeprties in RDF, one being more specific than the other.

Comment: *"these subproperties are not part of the old rdf:scheme"* - what does this mean?

Comment: So little by little this is what is happening:
I am using this as my basis: http://purl.org/procurement/public-contracts#

within contracts, there are various types of procedures. Now tried this:

<rdf:type rdf:Property="TipoProcedimento">
 <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:domain="pc.Contract">
 </rdf:type>
 </rdfs:subPropertyOf>

Comment: started with this:
</rdfs:Class>
   <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.org/procurement/public-contracts#"/>
     <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://purl.org/procurement/public-contracts"/>
     <rdfs:domain rdfs:Class="http://purl.org/procurement/public-contracts#

nothing is making sense

Comment: when I said that the old rdf:scheme within the original vocab didn't have theses subproperties, what i meant was that on the vocab that I was trying to use as "basis", it didn't have all the types of procurement procedures I needed

Comment: if you don't mind two comments here: 1. please do not post this in comments but instead edit your question 2.) please don't write RDF/XML but N-Triples or Turtle syntax. RDF/XML is rather verbose and not really made for humans.

Comment: that said, you quite often used `purl.org/procurement/public-contracts#` but this not a proper URI but just the namespace of the vocabulary. Like the domain of a property is supposed to be a class, but the class clearly isn't identified by `purl.org/procurement/public-contracts#` - I mean, what is the name of the class? You know what I mean, like person, book, place etc.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I apologize for the mistakes. New to this... Will do better next time. As regards to the name of the class it was meant to be "public contract".